# AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'list' in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When I tried to use the  App Engine Administration API in the python script it throws me the error

I tried the code sample from the  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/v1beta2/quickstart/

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def main():
  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = build('appengine', 'v1beta',
                  credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

  # Get a list of your applications.
  response = service.apps().list().execute()
  apps_list = response.get('apps', [])

  for app in apps_list:
    print ('App Title: ', app['title'])
    print ('App ID: ', app['appId'])

    # List all modules on the application.
    response = service.apps().modules().list(
        appId=app['appId']).execute()
    modules_list = response.get('modules', [])

    print ('  Modules for this app:')
    for module in modules_list:
      print ('    Module ID: ', module['moduleId'])

      # List all versions on this module.
      response = service.apps().modules().versions().list(
          appId=app['appId'],
          moduleId=module['moduleId']).execute()
      versions_list = response.get('versions', [])

      print ('      Versions on this module: ')
      for version in versions_list:
        print ('        Version ID: ', version['versionId'])
        print ('        Runtime: ', version['runtime'])
        print ('        Deployment Timestamp: ', version['deployedTimestamp'])
        if version['isDefault']:
          print ('        ** This is the default version. **')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I m getting the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 21, in main
    response = service.apps().list().execute()
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'list'
```

Comment: Mismatch in Python versions. The code is written for Python 2 and you are trying to use Python 3.

Comment: Where can u  find the python 3 version code

Comment: I do not know, I did not write that code. Check with the author.